# Accessing external JS functions in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: html5-canvas, adobe-javascript, adobe-cc

In my Animate CC file I can handle the loading of external js files, but am struggling to understand how you access the functions in those external files from the timeline? For example, if my external script has:

```
function videoPlay() {
    alert("Hello! I am some code!");
}
```

How would I call that function from a keyframe on the timeline?

this.videoPlay(); or _root.videoPlay();  does not work

Answer (score 0):

videoPlay();  is the correct way to call the method. I had an issue elsewhere in the code where I did not implicitly call this. on a variable.